# Magento get layout for given page

Tags: magento

I'm working on a Magento module where i want to fetch the layout from a frontend page. By frontend page i mean all types of pages, i.e. cms page, category, product, cart, my account, etc.

I've read the excellent magento-nofrills ebook from Alan Storm and i'm using his Commercebug plugin to help me develop my magento site. I've also spent some time on stackoverflow looking for a similair question, please forgive me if i have missed it.

If for example i have a page id or category id, how do i fetch the layout of that frontend page from code run in the backend?

I've been playing with the request and when i run this code in the frontend i can see that the module, controller, layouthandles etc are changed when for instance looking at a catalog page

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$request->setModuleName('cms');
$request->setRouteName('cms');
$request->setControllerName('page');
$request->setActionName('view');
$request->setParam('page_id', 6);
```

But when i inspect the xml from the layout, i can't seem to force magento to show me the xml for (in this example) cms page with id=6:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getNode()->asXml();
```

Maybe i'm thinking way too complicated though. I would like to check if a certain page has sidebars, which blocks and elements are shown on the page and in the sidebars (only active blocks, not the ignored ones).

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Comment: Did you figure this out? i'm curious myself.

Answer (score 7):

Call loadLayout() before getLayout().

You can check if a block is active in the layout by calling getBlock($block_name):

```
$left_block = $this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('left');
```

If the block isn't part of the layout (or is ignored) then $left_block will be false.
You can use getBlock() in conjunction with getSortedChildren() to see its child blocks:

```
$this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->getSortedChildren();
```

The above will return a string array of block names within the "content" block. Only names of active blocks will be returned.

Comment: I tried to use your snippet to get $left_block;
but I got an exception error. Is there anything I should add before that line of code?

Comment: Where did you place the code? The example above belongs in the controller file.

Comment: owh... I need to use it on a phtml file... is there any way I could do that? I'm asking it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133522/magento-get-which-layout-being-used-on-phtml-files . would be glad if you could answer it :)